# Cocoa Touch project with ARC error: [__NSCFString deviceOrientationDidChange:]: unrecognized selector

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, automatic-ref-counting, device-orientation

I've got the Cocoa Touch project with ARC and this error sometimes occurs. Can You explain me the kind of this error and the way to solve this?

```
-[__NSCFString deviceOrientationDidChange:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1ddf81a0

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString deviceOrientationDidChange:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1ddf81a0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x313132a3 0x38fad97f 0x31316e07 0x31315531 0x3126cf68 0x31264037 0x31b7a599 0x33121c65 0x3311c3db 0x3311b6cd 0x3311b11b 0x34e1c5a3 0x34e1c1d3 0x312e8173 0x312e8117 0x312e6f99 0x31259ebd 0x31259d49 0x34e1b2eb 0x3316f301 0x14b61 0x14ae8)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a zombie problem.  If you can reproduce this on the simulator, run it under the Zombies instrument.  If you can only reproduce it on the device, edit your scheme, go to the Diagnostics tab, and turn on the zombies checkbox there.  (Instruments doesn't offer zombie detection on the device, unfortunately.)

Comment: thanks, I think it will very useful for me, I did not know about it

Answer (score 1):

The crash you're seeing has *nothing* to do with ARC and everything to do with the object (which appears to be a NSCFString object) that's receiving a bogus "`deviceOrientationDidChange:`" message.

My recommendation would be to set a symbolic breakpoint on "`deviceOrientationDidChange`" and catch the message being sent and then you'll know what line of code is broken.

Comment: where (how) I can find deviceOrientationDidChange to set a symbolic breakpoint?